# Invoking jquery from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to make a `HyperLink` blink (customer requirement unfortunately) so I've decided to  use [this](http://labs.wondergroup.com/demos/mini-ui/jquery.blink.min.js).

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to invoke this from the code behind (C#)?

So far I've tried:

```
private string script1 = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\" src=\"javascripts/jquery.blink.min.js\"></script>";
private string script2 = "$(\".selector\").blink();";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(e.Item.FindControl("hlink"), e.Item.FindControl("hlink").GetType(),
                    "BlinkingScript", script1, false);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(e.Item.FindControl("hlink"),
                                                    e.Item.FindControl("hlink").GetType(),
                                                    "BlinkingScript", script2, false);
```

..to no avail

Comment: Why don't you put the javascript in your html? you need the charset attribute in your script tag? you need to do `$(document).ready();` when you want your selector to work

Comment: never really used/needed javascript (i'm just starting web dev). in my code i need to iterate through a collection and only make certain hyperlinks blink.

Comment: Then assign them a CSS class and use a jQuery selector to find the items that have that class.

Comment: It actually looks like that's kind of what you're trying to do, just in a convoluted way.  Your selector in the jQuery (script2) isn't matching your items because it's looking for any item that has CSS class "selector".

Answer (score 2):

Trying to mess around with `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `RegisterStartupScript` is painful, and is completely unnecessary except in some extremely off-radar edge cases.  Not only is it extremely difficult to maintain, it's also difficult to understand.  And in this case the simple, direct approach will work much better for you.

In the `<head>` block of your page, add the following:

```
<!-- Assuming that you've already got jQuery registered... -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.blink.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Couple of notes here:
        // ".blinky" means that it will match anything with a CSS class of "blinky".  This can be anything, not just hyperlinks.
        // Also, I'm adding an optional object parameter to the blink() method that allows me to specify parameters that alter its behavior.
        // In this case, if I just called blink() it would only blink 3 times, but I'm overriding that to blink 5 times.
        $(".blinky").blink({blinks: 5});
    });
</script>
```

Then, in the body of your page, add the `CssClass="blinky"` on the hyperlinks that you want to blink.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Not Blinky Link" /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Not Blinky Link" /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Blinky Link" CssClass="blinky" /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Not Blinky Link" /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Blinky Link" CssClass="blinky" /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Blinky Link" CssClass="blinky" /><br />
```

You can also use an `asp:Repeater`, code-behind, etc. to construct your Hyperlink items, just as long as you set the CssClass on the ones you want to blink.